# Initializing a StringCollection from My.Settings to avoid null reference exception

Tags: c#, vb.net, nullreferenceexception, stringcollection

I am specifying a System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection named MyCollection in My.Settings, and upon first use to add a string, a null reference exception is being thrown (i.e. MyCollection is Nothing).

The syntax to add a string is simply:

```
My.Settings.MyCollection.Add(myString)
```

How can I initialize a StringCollection from My.Settings if it is null upon first use?

There have been reports of .NET Framework conflicts and StringCollections in My.Settings.  Thus, I have .NET Framework 4.6 specified in the project's app settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open the project properties, settings, and click the 3 dots button to open the string collection editor.
- Add a single string and Click OK
- Open the editor again and remove the string you added

Now your settings grid should look like this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

And in runtime your settings will be a collection with 0 entries instead of a Nothing collection i.e. it won't crash when you try to use it

Comment: I figured it out myself before coming back to look at answers, and did exactly this, and it worked.

Comment: I always thought it was a bit strange that Microsoft put the default as Nothing, because it's not very intuitive for the user.. maybe they assumed it would always be filled with at least one setting..

Comment: Yes - it's truly strange.   Lists are not Nothing after using `Dim myList As New List(Of String)`.  I just didn't click on the Items (`...` button) in Settings, then add one empty string.

Comment: Well, lists are nothing if you say `Dim myList as List(Of String)`.. but I get your point - I couldn't ever see the use case for anyone adding a setting of a string collection type but it not actually being usable..

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check if the StringCollection is `nothing` using a conditional statement:

```vb
If (My.Settings.MyCollection Is Nothing) Then
    My.Settings.MyCollection = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection() ' you probably won't need to fully qualify this, but I have it for visibility
End If
My.Settings.MyCollection.Add(myString)
```

Comment: Thanks, but testing for nullity fails because the collection wasn't initialized.  (I tried this before asking the question). You have to follow the procedures provided by @Caius Jard.